# Why isn't '&' used for logical conjunction?

Tags: logic, notation, math-history

There is a beautiful and well-established logogram for "and" that is known to virtually every more or less educated person in the world - it's the ampersand '&'. It's completely unambiguous, as opposed to logical disjunction (I'm talking about its inclusive and exclusive versions).

**Why is the ampersand not used universally to denote logical conjunction?**

The best answer I can come up with is because actually drawing the symbol takes a bit of knack. However, there are two reasons this is not an answer:

1. Drawing Greek letters takes quite a bit of knack as well, and they are all over the place in mathematics and logic.
2. There are handwritten variations of the ampersand that are extremely easy to draw.

   **Is using '$\wedge$' for logical conjunction just a historical accident?**

P.S. I was of course lying when I said the ampersand is not used *universally*, as I have seen it used here and there, and I use it myself in my own writing.

Comment: I don't think, this is a bad question, but it isn't about mathematics. It's just notation. Sometimes notation can be extremely useful, like the case of matrices, the Leibnitz-notation in calculus, or even Young-diagrams, but in this case the notation doesn't play an important role by the thoughts. Yes, it's a tradition to use this sign. It has an advance: the sign of conjunction is similar to the set theoretically sign of intersection.

Comment: I disagree. There are notations more expressive, useful, practical than others. It's about mathematics.

Comment: As I get older, I'll pay more attention to the philosophy of mathematics. As I was younger, I paid more attention to it, but I'm a born platonist. Now, if I would not feel myself being sterile, I'd love to pay more attention to the praxis of mathematics. And I need only the philosophy that makes me more able to create mathematics.

Comment: @Constantine just like painting is not about brushes, but a question about a new style of brush certainly is of interest and belongs to world of painting, so is mathematics not about notation, but a question about some notational style is of interest and belongs to the world of mathematics.

Comment: Um, did someone get bugs-bunnied here? If my eyes are not deceiving me, it looks like the OP is now arguing that his own question is off-topic on the site ...

Answer (score 9):

In older books (certainly up to about 1960) it is not unusual to see conjunction notated `&`, and there are still authors and fields that use it. (Consider for example *linear logic* which has two different conjunctions notated $\otimes$ and $\&$, and eschews the $\land$ symbol completely).

Jeff Miller's excellent [Earliest Uses of Various Mathematical Symbols](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathsym.html) lists $\land$ as having been invented by Heyting in 1930. By then, $\lor$ for disjunction had already been in use for for decades -- it was apparently invented by Russell in 190x and used in *Principia Mathematica*.

Heyting's motivation for $\land$ may have been to stress the duality between $\lor$ and $\land$, or to call out the parallel between $\land,\lor$ and $\cap,\cup$ in set theory (which were introduced by Peano as early as 1888).

The new notation became popular enough that when ASCII was invented in the early 1960s, the primary motivation for including a `\` character seems to have been that then matching $\land$ and $\lor$ symbols could be created in computer printouts as `/\` and `\/`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer shining a bit of light on the issue, I appreciate it, sir.

Comment: you may wish to correct the year for Peano. I doubt he practiced mathematics in 1988....

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Whoops, 1888 of course.

Comment: Linear logic also has ⅋, to make things more fun.